# How to exclude any function from union

Tags: typescript

```
type X = (() => void) | (() => number) | string

type Y = Something<X> // string
```

How to filter/exclude all function from type `X`

So type `Y` will be `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something like @colinD answer but the `Function` type is changed to `(...args: any[]) => any` because when I use `Function` type eslint typescript throws

```
Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value.
It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs.
It also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with `new`.
If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape  @typescript-eslint/ban-types
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) and the `Function` types:

```
type X = (() => void) | (() => number) | string

type Y = Exclude<X, Function> // string
```

Comment: There is [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UAUSCUCB8UBuB7AlgCboA+yamUAdgK4C2ARhAE6lQDOwz+VA5gFD9QkKAE0EUAKIAPAMYAbGoQgAeGABooAMRpVZwfLipYA9CY5ceA-kA).